# How to use env variables in Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, environment-variables, azure-pipelines, pytest

I have the following azure task that copies my .env file from secure files (library) in Azure to the working diretory from which I execte unit tests:

```
steps:
  - task: DownloadSecureFile@1
    inputs:
      secureFile: '.env'
    displayName: "Download .env file"
  - task: CopyFiles@2
    inputs:
      sourceFolder: "$(Agent.TempDirectory)"
      contents: ".env"
      targetFolder: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)"
    displayName: "Copy .env"
  - script: |
      cd /$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)
      sudo apt-get update
      sudo apt-get install -y python3-dev default-libmysqlclient-dev build-essential unixodbc-dev
      pip3 install -r requirements.txt
      pip3 install pytest pytest-azurepipelines
      pip3 install pytest-cov
      python3 -m pytest --doctest-modules --junitxml=junit/test-results.xml --cov=. --cov-report=xml
```

However when running pytest its failing because Python cannot find the environment variables from the file. Is there something I am missing that I need to do so that Pytest can successfully run the tests with all the environment variables that are coming from the `.env` file?

Comment: you need to add a script that read the file and create the env variables

Comment: To read key value pairs from a `.env` file, use the library [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/). Is that library present in your `requirements.txt` file & have you implemented it? I have slightly modified your `yaml` file and tested it using a `.env` file (from secure file library) and it is working. Please let me know if both the `yaml` and the python file needs to be shared.

Comment: @pnkjkmr469 I am using `on.environ.get()` to read env variables. Do I need to swap them with python-dotenv somehow?

Comment: If you are trying to use the key value pairs from your `.env` file, you should definitely go for python-dotenv. 
`on.environ.get()` is used to read the system environment variables like `HOME` , `HOSTNAME`, etc...

Comment: @pnkjkmr469 But os.environ.get() should also be able to parse variables stored in `.env` file right?

Comment: @AlexT The [os](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#module-os) module provides functions for interacting with the operating system. The process of setting or changing an environment variable (in your OS) is time consuming. Using a `.env` file will enable you to use environment variables for local development without polluting the global environment namespace. To summarize, `os.environ.get()` is used to read host environment variables whereas python-dotenv is used to read variables from your `.env` file.

Comment: @pnkjkmr469 would python-dotenv also be able to read environment variables set in the system (for example loaded into docker container during build) similarly like `os` module?